# Stack messageboard uploads compactly in order, one under eachother in rows of 5, but dont let tall images interfere

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, frontend

I have some kind of message board, users can add images, videos, markdown text.

[How I want it to behave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKHJx.png)

I want items to align like in the image provided; move the blue element to the red area, as it should. the uploads (messages) are all the same width, but different heights, also, They are added by a PHP script which loops through a database and adds elements to the "message board" div, with the ".uploads" class.
if provided an image or video, theres an image or video, if not, theres only text.

home.php (shortened to the point...)

```
<?php
session_start();

// Check if user is logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
     <div class="functions-holder">
          <h1>Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h1>
          <?php if (isset($_GET['msg'])) { ?>
               <p class="message"><?php echo $_GET['msg']; ?></p>
           <?php } ?>
          <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
          <button onclick="openPopup()" class="fa-solid fa-plus" id="popUp"> Add post</button>
     </div>
     <div id="message-board"">
     </div>
     <script src="board.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
} else {
?>
<!-- ... pretty similar... -->
```

Sample of board.php

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $html .= '<div class="uploads">';
    // Only display the delete button if the logged-in user is "chips"
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && $_SESSION['user_name'] === "chips") {
        $html .= '<button class="delete-button" data-id="' . $row['postid'] . '">Delete</button>';
    }
    $html .= '<h2>' . $row['author'] . ' shared</h2>';
    $html .= '' . $row['markdown'] . '';
    // Display the image if it exists and is not "noimg"
    if ($row['img'] != '' && $row['img'] != 'noimg'){
        $mimeType = mime_content_type($row['img']);
        $fileType = explode('/', $mimeType)[0];
        if (str_contains($fileType, 'image')){
            $html .= '<img src="' . $row['img'] . '"/>';
        }
        else if (str_contains($fileType, 'video')){
            $html .= '<video controls width="380" height="auto" src="' . $row['img'] . '"/>';
        }
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
}
```

How could I do this using; HTML, CSS, and JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .uploads {position: relative;float:left;width: 19%;border:1px dotted #000;margin:3px;height: 365px;width: 365px;background-color: #999;overflow: hidden;}
        .uploads h2 {float:left;height: 30px;}
        .uploads button {float:right;height: 30px;}
        .uploads .markdown {float:left;clear: both;height: 20px;width: 100%;}
        .uploads img {position: relative;float: none;display: block;clear: both;width:auto;height: auto;max-height: 285px; max-width: 330px;margin: 0px auto;clear: both;}
        hr {width:100%;float:left;clear:both;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$i=1;
$html = '';
while ($i<7) {
    $html .= '<div class="uploads">';
    // Only display the delete button if the logged-in user is "chips"

        $html .= '<button class="delete-button" data-id="x' . $i . '">Delete</button>';
    
    $html .= '<h2>xauthor shared</h2>';
    $html .= '<div class="markdown">xmarkdown</div>';
    // Display the image if it exists and is not "noimg"

            $html .= '<img src="' . $i . '.png"/>';
        
//        else if (str_contains($fileType, 'video')){
//            $html .= '<video controls width="380" height="auto" src="' . $row['img'] . '"/>';
//        }
    
    $html .= '</div>';
    if(($i%5)==0) {
        $html .= '<br/><hr/><br/>';
    }
    $i++;
}
echo $html;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I didnt want to do. I wanted to keep the non fixed height. I decided after all to use fixed height and non fixed width to still make it look like more than squares.